# WeaseyPrint Formats a PDF incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, web, flask, weasyprint

I'm trying to create a PDF from a HTML file which I also want to pass variables into for a JINJA template to pick it up. At the moment I've been trying to use weasyprint to do so with:

```py
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS

css = CSS(string='@page { size: A3; margin: 0cm }')
html = HTML('/home/templates/pdf_test.html')

html.write_pdf('test.pdf', stylesheets=[css])
```

How would I then refactor this to send variables to the HTML so before the PDF is created? I'm using flask for my framework and the HTML contains JINJA templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution might be slightly convoluted, but it works so i'll add it here for anyone who reads this...

```py
from weasyprint import HTML

@leads.route("/create-quote/<int:lead_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def generate_pdf(lead_id):
    post = Quote.query.get_or_404(lead_id)
    html_template = render_template('leads/pdf_test.html', post=post)
    HTML(string=html_template).\
        write_pdf('DESTINATION_OF_FILE/{}_quote.pdf'.format(post.business_name),
                  stylesheets=['PATH_TO_CSS_FOR_PDF'])
    flash('Your quote email has been generate! Please see var/b2b/quotes', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('main.dashboard'))
```

So we query the table for the data we want to populate the pdf - `post = Quote.query.get_or_404(lead_id)`

We then render the HTML passing post as an argument in since my jinja is `{{ post.[variable] }}`

Using WeaseyPrint we can create a HTML object passing in the populated HTML and the CSS for the PDF.

There might be a better way to do this, please feel free to post a better solution, but this dynamically creates PDF's based off a HTML template.

Comment: from weasyprint import HTML
it show error .can you help me Sir

Comment: try; https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/308